# Grouping dataframe weekly and summing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following (truncated) daily data which I wish to group into weekly data (fridays), and therefore summing the daily data in columns A and B. the Date column is already correctly formatted as a date time object. I do not want to use resampler because I lose the index. I suspect I need Grouper function but I cannot get this to work as I need to sum two columns.

```
data = {'Date' : ['2020-08-01','2020-08-02','2020-08-03','2020-08-04','2020-08-05','2020-08-06'],
        'A' : [7,6,5,3,3,11],
        'B' : [10,5,2,5,6,8]
       }

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date','A','B'])

#would look like this after grouping by week:

data = {'Date' : ['2020-08-07'],
        'A' : [35],
        'B' : [36]
       }

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date','A','B'])
```

Comment: You can change the value of `Data` to your desired one then use the `groupby()` function based on your sample. `df['Date'] = '2020-08-07'` then `df.groupby(['Date']).sum()`.

Comment: `df.set_index('Date').resample('1W-FRI').sum().reset_index()`